# Firebase-functions-test "The default Firebase app does not exist."

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I've begun using the new [firebase-functions-test](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test) testing SDK to unit test my **Cloud Firestore** functions. When I run my tests via `npm test` I am getting the following error:

`The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services`

My method is very similar to the `makeUppercase` method found within the [quickstarts samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/uppercase/functions/index.js), and thus I have mainly copied the test from the [test.js](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/uppercase/functions/test/test.offline.js) file.

```
describe('updateActiveNotesCount', () => {

    // Test Case: Setting environments/{environment}/users/{userId}/people/{personId}/notes/{noteId}/isActive to 'true' should cause
    // .../{personId}/activeNotesCount to be incremented

    it('Should increment active notes count on the person field', () => {
      // [START assertOffline]
      const childParam = 'activeNotesCount'; // The field to set
      const setParam = '1'; // the new activeNotesCount

      const childStub = sinon.stub();
      const setStub = sinon.stub();

      // A fake snap to trigger the function
      const snap = {
        // I believe this represents event params, wildcards in my case
        params: {
          userId: () => '1',
          personId: () => '2',
          environment: () => 'dev',  
        },
        // Not ENTIRELY sure how to write this one out
        ref: {
          parent: {
            child: childStub
          }
        }
      };
      childStub.withArgs(childParam).returns({ set: setStub });
      setStub.withArgs(setParam).returns(true);

      const wrapped = test.wrap(myFunctions.updateActiveNotesCount);

      return assert.equal(wrapped(snap), true);
      // [END assertOffline]
    })
  });
```

I am unable to move past this error.

**Edit:**
I see they now updated the docs to include the new SDK, and they mention config values must be mocked. In my `index.js`, I use:

```
const config = functions.config().firebase
admin.initializeApp(config);
```

I try to mock it like this now:

```
before(() => {
    // [START stubAdminInit]
    test.mockConfig({ firebase: 'FakeId' });

    adminInitStub = sinon.stub(admin, 'initializeApp');

    myFunctions = require('../index');
    // [END stubAdminInit]
  });
```

But no luck.

**End Edit**

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: put the `initializeApp()` AFTER the `config` object and make sure these are at the top of your script.

Comment: Since I am trying to do an offline (mocked) test, I'm not sure it's necessary. In the example above they don't create a config object, but in the [online example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/uppercase/functions/test/test.online.js#L27) they do

Comment: See line 24 `const sinon = require('sinon');` then line 42 `adminInitStub = sinon.stub(admin, 'initializeApp');`. Not sure what or where 'sinon' is though...

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and no matter how I tried I could not stub initializeApp. The workaround I found was to call `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);` in the beginning of the TEST file.

So, instead of stubbing `config` and `firebase` and `initializeApp`, just do this:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

describe('Cloud Functions', () => {
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
    before(() => {
        const index = require('../index');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:

Key point: you have to explicitly init the app within the test framework and THEN stub it out

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const assert = chai.assert;
const sinon = require('sinon');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const test = require('firebase-functions-test')();


describe('Functions', () => {
  let _fns, adminInitStub;

  before(() => {
    test.mockConfig({ YOUR_CONFIG }); 
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
    adminInitStub = sinon.stub(admin, "initializeApp");
    _fns = require('../index');
  });

  after(() => {
    test.cleanup();
  });

  describe('when test case blah', () => {
    // Test Case: setting messages/{pushId}/original to 'input' should cause 'INPUT' to be written to
    // messages/{pushId}/uppercase
    it('should do xyz', () => {
      assert(1 + 1, 2);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test/issues/38

My solution...

```
// IMPORTS
const chai = require('chai');
const assert = chai.assert;
const sinon = require('sinon');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const test = require('firebase-functions-test')();

// TESTS
describe('Cloud Functions', () => {
  let myFunctions, adminInitStub;

  before(() => {
    // ORDER REQUIRED
    // 1) Calling 'exampleDocumentSnapshot' only way to initialize testing app
    test.firestore.exampleDocumentSnapshot()

    // 2) Prevents multiple initializeApp calls
    adminInitStub = sinon.stub(admin, 'initializeApp');

    // 3) Import functions
    myFunctions = require('../');
  });
```