# how to initializeApp in firebase with admin privilege

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

i have this error when i trying to initialize app with firebase : 
***"The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services."***

this is my script :

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const servicesAccount = require("./admin.json");

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const firebase = require("firebase");
const firebaseConfig = {...};

const database = admin.firestore();

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(servicesAccount),
  databaseURL: "...",
});
```

and then all my routes...

Comment: Can you check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52693845/13130697) works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `initializeApp()` **before** any other methods on the Admin object.  Change the order of statements like this:

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(servicesAccount),
  databaseURL: "...",
});

const database = admin.firestore();
```

Note that `admin.firestore()` comes after `initializeApp()`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if you want to interact, from a Cloud Function, with the Firebase back-end services (Firestore, the Realtime Database, Cloud Storage, etc.) you just need to initialize the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin) [with no parameters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-without-parameters)

> In this case, the SDK uses Google Application Default Credentials and
>   reads options from the FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable. ... The
>   FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable **is included automatically in
>   Cloud Functions for Firebase functions that were deployed via the
>   Firebase CLI**.

Have also a look at the following section of the Cloud Functions doc: [new initialization syntax for `firebase-admin`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#new_initialization_syntax_for_firebase-admin).

---

On the other hand, you do the following

```
const firebaseConfig = {...};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

when you want to use the **Firebase JavaScript SDK** in your web app or as a client for end-user access, for example, in a Node.js desktop or IoT application.

---

So, in conclusion, you should do something like:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const database = admin.firestore();

//....
```